# Reorder date format with regex

Tags: regex

I have a lot of bank statements which are provided with the prefix DDMMYYYY. This is useless for sorting, very unintuitive (to me, anyway).

Is there a regex expression that can reorder the name so the files are prefixed in YYYYMMDD?

Thanks in advance. I looked at some of the posts answering similar questions and found it a bit beyond me.

Comment: You can collect groups and then output them in the order you wish, but which language are you using?

Comment: I believe that is the run-of-the-mill standard order for dates in a lot of languages. But YYYYMMDD (which is intuitive for Japanese, programmers using ISO dates, and maybe nobody else) is certainly more useful for sorting.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I think that question was about which programming language the OP is using. :-)

Comment: @qwrrty I wasn’t replying to Duniyadnd.

Comment: Thanks all, this was sorted by falsetru, I was using a Mac file name changer program which had the flexibility to define changes in regex format. Sorry if my question was vague. Cheers Craig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use capturing group.

For example, here's a javascript code:

```
> '09122013'.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$3$2$1')
"20131209"
```

Comment: Done, sorry. Cheers Craig